# Async function to get JSON returns nothing

Tags: vue.js

I have the following function in my project that I access from several files.

```
getCountry: async function () {
  let country = null
  try {
    axios
    .get('http://ip-api.com/json/')
    .then(response => (this.country = response.data.countryCode))
    console.log('Country', country)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  return country
}
```

It works on the other files, but for some reason I cannot use it successfully in a particular file with this situation.

This is my data part:

```
 data() {
    return {
      model: {
        country: '',
        state: '',
        city: ''
      },
      country: null
    }
  },
```

And on mount part I am trying to do the following:

```
this.country = await this.getCountry()
if (this.country != null) {
  this.model.country = this.country
}
```

The value never gets assigned to model.country.
When I check this.country value, it gets the result from the function.
I suppose it might have something to do with the fact that it's an async function, but I am not sure what to do.

Comment: In your browser's network check if its calling the api or not and share complete info

Comment: It does call with success status~

Comment: I think that the function doesn't have time to complete before it gets assigned to model.country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` should be used inside an `async` function, not outside it.
Please try

```
getCountry: async function () {
  let country;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://ip-api.com/json/');
    country = response.data.countryCode;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  return country
}
```